# Reflecting a line over a plane

Tags: vectors

I'm trying to solve a problem described in the image below, but I can't figure out where I've gone wrong as the position vector of my answer does not reduce to the answer in the book(2nd image)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRFhZ.jpg
I'm certain that its an error with my line of reasoning because when I repeat with another point, I get a different line.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281503/reflecting-a-point-by-a-line-in-mathbb-r3

Comment: Please take the time to enter critical parts of your question (in this case, pretty much all of it) as text instead of pasting pictures of it. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen readers. You can find a quick reference for MathJax, which is used for formatting mathematical expression on MSE, [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Where did $(6,-5,6)$ come from at the stage in which you computed the projection of $(-2,2,-2)$ onto the plane? You also dropped a sign in that computation.

Comment: You say you are trying to solve "a problem described in the image below". But that image does not define the problem. If is a solution that assumes one already knows what the problem is. Post the problem, not just the book's and your solutions. As as amd requests, please post the problem in your question instead of images.